# C# architecture for large application

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Can you please tell me some tutorials/books about thinking a large application in c#.
I have worked with 3 tier, but i need something more specific:

a way to design panels, so that for specific users specific panels will load and specific dlls
a database management so that when a user modifies an entry, others can not modify that entry
should i use entity framework or should i go old school with db and class creation

any links on the above will be greatly appreciated

thanks a lot!

Comment: didn't downvote but your question is kinda vague and the description is a bit... confusing.  Try splitting this into a question about the type of book you're looking for (be as specific about architecture as you can) and maybe another/other question/s about your requirements and how you see the design.

Comment: I see the entity-framework tag, it is really slow in my opinion

Comment: 100% agree with Will, but lets see if we can help.

Answer (score 3):

Kind of a broad subject but two books I would recommend giving a read regardless of what language you are doing or the specifics of your project:

- [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)
- [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

If you have specific questions about how to accomplish something I would post it on here or google it.

Comment: i am familiar with design patterns. on the gui side i am new. what i mostly desire for now is some guide on making those panels

Comment: @psu what UI framework do you want to use: Silverlight/WPF/WinForms?

Answer (score 2):

NDepend documentation comes with [two white books](http://www.ndepend.com/WhiteBooks.aspx) and also online blog posts and articles concerning the architecture for large .NET application:

- [Partitioning code base through .NET assemblies and Visual Studio projects](http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependWhiteBook_Assembly.pdf) (8 pages)
- [Defining .NET Components with Namespaces](http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependWhiteBook_Namespace.pdf) (7 pages)
- [Control Components Dependencies to gain Clean Architecture](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ControllingDependencies)
- [Re-factoring, Re-Structuring and the cost of Levelizing](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/02/15/re-factoring-re-structuring-and-the-cost-of-levelizing.aspx)
- [Evolutionary Design and Acyclic componentization](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/02/22/evolutionary-design-and-acyclic-componentization.aspx)
- [Layering, the Level metric and the Discourse of Method](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/02/10/layering-the-level-metric-and-the-discourse-of-method.aspx)
- [Fighting Fabricated Complexity](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/06/28/fighting-fabricated-complexity.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**That's not gonna be covered by a single book or tutorial.**

You need to decide a UI framework, data access technology, patterns and the overall architecture. And of course you need an in-depth knowledge on .NET framework, & how the CLR works. It's nothing C# specific. Since you have UI customization (Panels) requirements, WPF is definitely a better candidate for UI framework, than WinForms.

That being said, my recommendations -

- For C#: [Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225491)
- .NET & CLR: [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045)
- UI Framework - WPF: [Pro WPF in C# 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430272058)
- Use [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) with WPF. MVVM will keep you on track maintaining the [Separation of Concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). You can follow Microsoft's [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx) guideline. For large applications with sophisticated UI requirements Prism is a better choice. You might need to use Dependency Injection. [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) is there to go hand-to-hand with MVVM & Prism.
- Yes, Entity Framework can handle concurrency issues, but such feature is available in almost any other data access framework. Entity Framework provides lots of other facilities, but when using it you should have clear idea of what you're doing. Otherwise you might end up with performance issues. [Programming Entity Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596807260) is definitely gonna help.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the panels/UI architecture, it might be useful to look at [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) (from Microsoft patterns & practices).  It's an architecture/set of libraries to handle composite UI, where the UI is loaded at runtime and composed of independent communicating parts.  One note, it is built for use with WPF or Silverlight; there is an older library with similar functionality for WinForms, called "[CAB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648747.aspx)", that is no longer supported.

As far as data access, it sounds like you are looking to implement active record locking while a record is open for editing in the UI; this is an independent feature from the actual data access code you use.  It might be easier to implement database-level locking if you are using straight ADO.NET versus EF, which adds layers of abstraction.

Comment: Please don't use CAB.  The functionality does not support newer versions of visual studio so unless you are using VS2008, you will not be able to use the famework's Guidance Automation Toolkit to generate the wiring between objects.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562609X) - with a very good code example and there is a chapter on concurrency

[Professional Enterprise .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470447613)

[ASP.NET 3.5 Website Programming: Problem - Design - Solution](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470187581)

I guess, there are not any online recources that could compete the complexity of these books.

Answer (score 0):

My go to book with these kinds of questions is [Jeffrey Richter's CLR via C#](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780735627048.do) book.  It takes you all the way from how your class construction impacts memory on the stack/heap to best practices for these types of discussions.  Especially loading assemblies on the fly and the best way to accomplish this.

It will also bring your skills up a notch and Jeff is a great writer.

I recommend this book to EVERY C# developer I know and they always come away better.  Is that what we all hope for?

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn fast and get to the meat of the technology fast, I would recommend getting a Pluralsight account as that would cover the technologies you would need and highlight others you may not have heard about. A monthly subscription would be about the same cost as a decent book.

[Pluralsight.com](http://www.pluralsight.com)